# Firebase - search data by phone number

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a site with a lesson schedule for teachers. For recording, a person indicates his phone number. I have been trying to find it by phone number for a long time, but it does not work.

[image: Understandable database example]

By phone number you need to find out all the days and hours when this number is used.
I am trying to do it like this:

```
ref = db.ref("/user1/");
ref.orderByChild("Phone").equalTo('+7 999 999 99 99').on("value", function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

null is displayed in the console

I almost got it. If you change ref to

```
ref = db.ref("/user1/28-07-2022");
```

then output to the console:

```
{
   '10-00': {
     Comment: 'DemoTest',
     Free: false,
     Name: 'Jack',
     Phone: '+7 999 999 99 99',
     Time: '10-00'
   }
 }
```

But this method only looks for one day. And I want to search everywhere

Comment: Is the "user1" the entire document in a particular collection? Can you show the collection and document structure?

Comment: Have you tried to change `db.ref("/user1/")` into `db.ref("user1")`. Does it work this way? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo ref = db.ref("user1") still returns null. collection and document structure in the screenshot above. For convenience, I have highlighted and signed everything

Comment: @Romanus Is that screenshot a single document of `users` collection?

Comment: @davidbilla Yes, this is the only document. As I said above, if ref = db.ref("/user1/28-07-2022") then everything works, but I need to search for all days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase can only order/filter on a value at a fixed path under each direct child node of the location you query. So you can for example filter on the keys/dates right under `user1`, or you can search for the `Phone` value for a specific date, but you **cannot** search across all phone number for all dates, let alone for across all dates for all users.

If you want to allow that you'll need to either:

- Maintain an additional flat list of time slots (for each user), for example putting the date as a property into each slot then, and query that.

  ```
    slots: {
      "2022-07-08T10:00": { ... },
      "2022-07-08T11:00": { ... },
      "2022-07-29T10:00": { ... },
      "2022-07-29T11:00": { ... }
    }
  ```
- Create a so-called reverse index, where you map from the phone number as a key back the dates/times for that number.

  ```
    phoneToSlots: {
      '+7 999 999 99 99": {
        "2022-07-08T10:00": true
      }
    }
  ```